# categories is undefined - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have a project resource which has categories nested into it the whole project structure is set up as such:

```
StartPoint::Application.routes.draw do
  get "log_out" => "sessions#destroy", :as => 'log_out'
  get "log_in"  => "sessions#new", :as => 'log_in'
  get "sign_up" => "users#new", :as => 'sign_up'

  root :to => 'Projects#index'

  resources :users
  resources :sessions
  resources :discussion_comments
  resources :comments

  resources :projects do
    resources :categories
    resources :duscussions
    resources :tasks
  end

end
```

now with that said on my tasks index page I am trying to render the categories form

```
<%= form_for project.categories.build do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :category%>
    <%= f.text_field :category%>
    <%= hidden_text_field :project_id, :value => project.id %>
    <%= f.submit%>
<% end %>
```

When I render this - I am passing the project object into this form:

```
<%= render 'categories/createcategory', :project => @project%>
```

This not rendered in the category index page, but in the tasks index page.

so, with that type of information (tell me if you need more) why the categories is apparently undefined.

**Error**

```
undefined method `categories' for #<Project:0xb687150c>

Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <%= form_for ([project, project.categories.build]) do |f| %>
2:  <%= f.label :category%>
3:  <%= f.text_field :category%>
4:  <%= hidden_text_field :project_id, :value => project.id %>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem in the form. It should probably be `form_for [@project, Category.new]`

You must make sure that in your project controllers, you have `@project` initialized.

Comment: So it didnt work.... No route matches {:controller=>"categories", :format=>nil, :project_id=>#<Project id: nil, project_title: nil, user_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>}