# no route matches in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

So I have been wrestling with this issue all night..... I essentialls have my resources set up as such:

```
resources :projects do
   resources :categories
end
```

and in my form partial I have:

```
<%= form_for ([@project, @category]) do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

It gives me the error:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"categories", :format=>nil, :project_id=>#<Project id: nil, project_title: nil, user_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>}

Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

how ever my routes for categories are:

```
     project_categories GET    /projects/:project_id/categories(.:format)           categories#index
                        POST   /projects/:project_id/categories(.:format)           categories#create
   new_project_category GET    /projects/:project_id/categories/new(.:format)       categories#new
  edit_project_category GET    /projects/:project_id/categories/:id/edit(.:format)  categories#edit
       project_category GET    /projects/:project_id/categories/:id(.:format)       categories#show
                        PUT    /projects/:project_id/categories/:id(.:format)       categories#update
                        DELETE /projects/:project_id/categories/:id(.:format)       categories#destroy
```

what is going on, why is this not working. I have tried everything, I have tried passing project variable into the render path and then doing: (gives me a diff error, complains that categories is undefined)

```
form_for project.categories.build do |f|
```

I have even tried

```
form_for ([project, project.categories.build]) do |f|
```

but this gives me the same error as above.

any ideas? I have Googled, I have read articles, read talks.....it **MUST** be something simple

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12327336/categories-is-undefined-rails/12327490#12327490.

Comment: I'm guessing that @project is not defined... is it set in the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your project is nil.  You need to have a project first.  What does your controller look like?  Is @project populated?

edit: To clarify, most likely your Categories > New method is the one in the controller that is relevant.

Comment: The category form is not being rendered in categories/index instead its being rendered in tasks/index as a task needs a category to be created before you can create a task.

with that said, in my tasks controller - I do have @project = Project.new under the index action, should it still go under the new action in categories?

Comment: Hmm, I think you are doing something incorrect there.  The way you set the form is for when you already have a project and are adding categories to the existing project).  I think what you want is "accepts_attributes_for" turned on and to use fields_for for the category.  That is how you create a new project and category at the same time.  See this http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Comment: I already have a project created, the url is localhost:3000/projects/1/tasks - the category form is rendered on the task index page. because you need to create a project, then create a category and THEN create a task., creating categories and tasks is done on the same page where as projects is not., so the project is def created.
and when I render this form, I do this: <%= render 'categories/createcategory', :project => @project %>

Comment: So why do you have Project.new in the controller action? You still need to set (@)project in the tasks new method.  It should be something like (@)project = Project.find(params[:project_id])

Comment: So I did as you suggested i put @project = Project.find(params[:project_id]) in the tasks new method and I still get the same error:

No route matches {:controller=>"categories", :format=>nil, :project_id=>#<Project id: nil, project_title: nil, user_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>}

This is my url http://localhost:3000/projects/1/tasks

Comment: Did you check that project_id is the right parameter for you? Make sure (@)project is now holding a real project, I am guessing that's your issue.  You can do "puts @project" after you assign it so that the logs will contain the contents of @project to see.

Answer (score 0):

try taking the space out of the function: `form_for(` ... Ruby often fails when there is a space btweein the method and opening parens

Comment: No route matches {:controller=>"categories", :format=>nil, :project_id=>#<Project id: nil, project_title: nil, user_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>}

Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.